# Table with spacing to have a solid background all the way through

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have alternating background colors however they have breaks in-between them due to the large spacing. I want the color to run through as though there was no spacing, so a solid bar all the way through.

```
tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Use `border-collapse: collapse;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
table{
    border-collapse: collapse; /* add this one */
}
```

[Demo with issue](http://jsbin.com/eGUyUwe/1/edit)
[Demo without issue](http://jsbin.com/eGUyUwe/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

In the table tag itself, use cellspacing="0" and cellpadding="0" to achieve the same effect but for browsers that don't (or poorly) support the border-collapse attribute.

You may also want to restore the lost space without creating gaps:

```
td{padding:2px 4px}
```